# Cassandra As Daemon

Tags: cassandra, apache-commons

I can't run cassandra as daemon. I set variable JAVA_HOME, CASSANDRA_HOME,PATH for cassandra. To running I use Apache Commons and tutorial [link](http://genesyslab.info/wiki/index.php?title=Cassandra)

but when i try started I see in console Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon

Tested on JDK 8 and 7

I do not know what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I found [error bug on CASSANDRA-7477](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-commits/201407.mbox/%3CJIRA.12724552.1404163029501.48196.1405456445253@arcas%3E)